# filtering by multiple conditions in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

so I have a dataframe which has been ordered by subject and by each subjects different diagnosis. As can be seen below several subjects have more than one diagnosis. What I would like is to isolate only the subjects with one diagnosis, that of Anorexia Nervosa. I have tried using the filter function in the dplyr package but so far I am having no luck. Here is a sample of the data

```
registeredunderid               diagnosis   social_skill_score 
            20145                    ADHD                    4
            20145        Anorexia Nervosa                    4
            20145         Bulimia Nervosa                    4
            20145              Depression                    4
            20145                      NA                    4
            20145                      NA                    4
            20145                      NA                    4
            20145                      NA                    4
            20145                      NA                    4
            20966        Anorexia Nervosa                    1
            20966                      NA                    1
            20966                      NA                    1
            20966                      NA                    1
            20966                      NA                    1
            20966                      NA                    1
            20966                      NA                    1
            20966                      NA                    1
            20966                      NA                    1
            21230        Anorexia Nervosa                    1
            21230                      NA                    1
            21230                      NA                    1
            21230                      NA                    1
            21230                      NA                    1
            21230                      NA                    1
            21230                      NA                    1
            21230                      NA                    1
            21230                      NA                    1
            27316        Anorexia Nervosa                    5
            27316         Bulimia Nervosa                    5
            27316              Depression                    5
            27316    Obsessive-Compulsive                    5
```

Thus any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Hi thanks for your comment. The expected output would be a dataframe of subjects with only Anorexia. All subjects with other conditions would be excluded

Comment: In 20966, there are NA values as well. Does it count?  It may be better to also show the expected output to avoid any confusion

Comment: Try `df %>% filter(diagnosis == "Anorexia_Nervosa")` after loading `dplyr`

Comment: @RStudent I think simple subset is not the OP asked for

Comment: May be `df1%>% group_by(registeredunderid) %>% filter(!is.na(diagnosis)) %>% filter(n_distinct(diagnosis)==1L & diagnosis=='Anorexia Nervosa')`

Comment: Hi
Thanks for your comments. I will amend my post to include what I hope will by the output and as @akrun said I am not looking for a simple subset. Rather I wish to exclude all subjects with more than one diagnosis. All subjects have AN but some have other conditions besides and these are the ones I want to exclude.

Comment: Or may be `df1%>% group_by(registeredunderid)%>% filter(n_distinct(diagnosis)==2L & diagnosis %in% c(NA, 'Anorexia Nervosa'))`
if you don't want to exclude NA values

Comment: @akrun that first answer appears to have done the trick thank you!

Comment: @googleplex101 I have a doubt regarding the `social_skill_score` column.  Does it reflect the number of unique elements in `diagnosis`?  In that case, we could remove one of the filter statements

Comment: Hi @akrun no it reflects a score on a questionnaire

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here we can remove the `NA` rows (`na.omit`), and `filter` those groups ('registeredunderid') with length of unique values in 'diagnosis' column as '1' (`n_distinct`) and the value as 'Anorexia Nervosa'

```
library(dplyr)
df1%>% 
   na.omit %>%
   group_by(registeredunderid) %>%
   filter(n_distinct(diagnosis)==1L & diagnosis=='Anorexia Nervosa')
```

Or using a similar approach with `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' with `setDT`, remove the NA rows (`na.omit`), based on the the condition as described above, we can subset the data by `group (.SD[...])`.  The equivalent function for `n_distinct` in data.table is `uniqueN` which was introduced in the devel version.

```
  library(data.table) #data.table_1.9.5
  na.omit(setDT(df1))[, .SD[uniqueN(diagnosis)==1L & 
          diagnosis=='Anorexia Nervosa'], by = registeredunderid]
 #   registeredunderid        diagnosis social_skill_score
 #1:             20966 Anorexia Nervosa                  1
 #2:             21230 Anorexia Nervosa                  1
```

Or as suggested by @Arun,

```
  na.omit(setDT(df1))[, .SD[all(diagnosis=='Anorexia Nervosa')],
                   by=registeredunderid]
```

Comment: `all(diagnosis == "Anorexia Nervosa")` is slightly easier.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a possible base R solution

```
indx <- with(na.omit(df), ave(as.character(diagnosis), 
             registeredunderid, FUN = function(x) length(unique(x))) == 1L & 
             diagnosis == 'Anorexia Nervosa')

na.omit(df)[indx, ]
#    registeredunderid        diagnosis social_skill_score
# 10             20966 Anorexia Nervosa                  1
# 19             21230 Anorexia Nervosa                  1
```